# Scraping with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Python3:
I'm new to scraping and to train I'm trying to get all the functions from this page:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.td.text)
# Output: abs()
```

no matter what I try, I only get the 1st one: abs()

Can you help me get them all from abs() to zip()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all similar tags from any webpage use `find_all()` it returns list of item .
To get all single tag use `find()` it returns single item.

trick is to get parent tag of all elements which you need then use different methods of your choice and convenience [Here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) you can find more.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

#scrape table which contains all functions
tabledata = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "w3-table-all notranslate"})
#print(tabledata)

#from table data get all a tags of functions
functions = tabledata.find_all("a")

#find_all() method returns list of elements iterate over it
for func in functions:
    print(func.contents)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. 
Quick question tho, I took off: , attrs={"class": "w3-table-all notranslate"} so I only put: table = soup.find('table')
and it worked too, does it mean that I could do it this way or it could lead to some errors on other pages?

Comment: it will work but I found more tables on page that's why added attribute parameter. This is static page so it wont trouble here, on dynamic pages you have to mention attributes where many similar tags present

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_all` to iterate through ancestors that match the selector:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('td'):
    print(tag.text)
```

This will include the Description column though, so you'll need to change this to ignore cells.

soup.td will only return the first matching tag.

So one solution would be:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cell = tag.td
    if cell:
        print(cell.text)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your help!